# In mongodb how do you do a pure update (not upsert) to replace an entire typed document?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to implement our CRUD interface using the C# MongoDB Driver. Our update method is supposed to throw an error if the record (with the same id as the passed-in model) does not exist.

- I know MongoCollection.Save can update a document based on the id,
  but it will also insert. I do not want to insert under any
  circumstances.
- I also want to avoid manually forming an update by specifying every
  member.
- I also want to avoid calling the mongo database twice E.g.;

  1. Check if the document exisits.
  2. Save if it does exist.

I am looking for something as close as possible to this:

```
var result = myCollection.Update(myModel, WriteConcern.Acknowledged);
//result will have an error if a document with Id==myModel.Id did not pre-exist
```

I would also be happy with somthing akin to:

```
var query = Query<MyModel>.EQ(m => m.Id, myModel.Id);
var update = Update<MyModel>.SetDocument(myModel);
var result = myCollection.Update(query, update, WriteConcern.Acknowledged);
```

Is there a 'proper' way to do this? If not, what mind-boggling alternative pattern to 'CRUD my models' am I supposed to use with Mongo DB?

Is there something I can set in MongoInsertOptions to achieve this (btw, if you create your own MongoInsertOptions, how do you initialize it with the defaults which would normally be used)?

Is there some hack way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: why can't you do a simple update and then check writeResult and if updatedExisting is false then the document didn't exist...

Comment: @Asya Kamsky How do you do a "simple update" of a strongly-typed object with the C# driver? Note that I do not want an insert to occur.

Comment: use update method.  insert will *never* occur with update unless you explicitly send the {upsert:true} flag.

Comment: @Asya Kamsky the question is, how? I need a example for the c# driver as I do not know how to do this. Note that I do not want to specify every updated field explicitly. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `Replace` what you are looking for?

```
var query = Query<MyModel>.EQ(m => m.Id, myModel.Id);
var update = Update<MyModel>.Replace(myModel);
var result = myCollection.Update(query, update, WriteConcern.Acknowledged);
```

http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/?topic=html/5e30d03f-b26a-3840-ce84-222f9804ca92.htm

And as Asya said, this will not perform an insert unless you explicitly use `UpdateFlags.Upsert`.

**Update**

In MongoDB C# Driver 2.x, replace is now achieved by a method on `IMongoCollection`.

```
await myCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(m => m.Id == myModel.Id, myModel);
```

Comment: It seems strange to me that there is no api to make the query implicit. What purpose does the query serve if the Id has to remain the same for Replace anyway?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that the devs didn't want to create a second API for what is essentially just a special case of `Update`. That said I personally think this case is special enough to warrant a separate API.